# Implementing Nested Order Set in MySQL/PHP

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, tree, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to create a database in which there could be `n` number of categories as well as their sub-categories.

First I tried to create adjacency model database like this

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
| category_id | name                 | parent |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|           1 | Electronics          |   NULL |
|           2 | Mobile               |      1 |
|           3 | Washing Machine      |      1 |
|           4 | Samsung              |      2 |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
```

but, I was facing a problem when deleting a node, like how to manage the child nodes for deleted nodes etc.

then I'm trying to implement Nested Order Set by [Joe Celko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Celko)
[image: sample_structure]

Table Structures in each Figure:

```
Figure 1:
+----+-------------+-----+-----+
| id | name        | lft | rgt |
+----+-------------+-----+-----+
| 1  | Electronics | 1   | 2   |
+----+-------------+-----+-----+

Figure 2:
+----+-------------+-----+-----+
| id | name        | lft | rgt |
+----+-------------+-----+-----+
| 1  | Electronics | 1   | 4   |
+----+-------------+-----+-----+
| 2  | Mobile      | 2   | 3   |
+----+-------------+-----+-----+

Figure 3:
+----+-----------------+-----+-----+
| id | name            | lft | rgt |
+----+-----------------+-----+-----+
| 1  | Electronics     | 1   | 6   |
+----+-----------------+-----+-----+
| 2  | Mobile          | 2   | 3   |
+----+-----------------+-----+-----+
| 3  | Washing Machine | 4   | 5   |
+----+-----------------+-----+-----+

Figure 4:
+----+-----------------+-----+-----+
| id | name            | lft | rgt |
+----+-----------------+-----+-----+
| 1  | Electronics     | 1   | 8   |
+----+-----------------+-----+-----+
| 2  | Mobile          | 2   | 5   |
+----+-----------------+-----+-----+
| 3  | Washing Machine | 6   | 7   |
+----+-----------------+-----+-----+
| 4  | Samsung         | 3   | 4   |
+----+-----------------+-----+-----+
```

but I'm unable to insert new node with correct `rgt` and `lft`.
I'm using this but it is not generating the right values of `rgt` and `lft`.

```
LOCK TABLE nested_category WRITE;

SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM nested_category
WHERE name = 'Mobile';

UPDATE nested_category SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myRight;
UPDATE nested_category SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;

INSERT INTO nested_category(name, lft, rgt) VALUES('LG', @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: How do you want to manage the child nodes? Do they become child of their grandparent or simply gets deleted with their parent?

Comment: Become child of grandparent

Comment: What should happen if the root node gets deleted, even if accidentally?

Comment: all children...n will be also deleted.

Comment: @jpm have you solved this question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ is your source code I think ?

You're not using the good query, this one is the **`add a brother node`**.

You're after the **`add a child node`** :

```
LOCK TABLE nested_category WRITE;

SELECT @myLeft := lft FROM nested_category
WHERE name = 'Mobile';

UPDATE nested_category SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;
UPDATE nested_category SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myLeft;

INSERT INTO nested_category(name, lft, rgt) VALUES('LG', @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nested_insert(_name VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
DECLARE _number int;
set @var=0;

-- first insert paramater value(_name) into nested_table
INSERT into nested_table(name) VALUE(_name);

-- count the total row  value from nested table;
SELECT count(*) from  nested_table into _number;

-- first update the all lft column from top to button by varibale with increment
UPDATE nested_table set lft=(@var:=@var+1) where id <=_number;

-- second update the all rgt column from button to top by varibale with increment in descending order id
UPDATE nested_table set rgt=(@var:=@var+1) where id<=(_number+1)*2 ORDER BY id desc ;
end;
```